# Angular JS 2.0 getting JSON data and displaying with Ng for

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am trying to loop through JSON data and display it in angular. so far i can display in the console with the use of a function, but not bind it to a div or the loop. iv'e been looking through other posts, but their http requests don't work, this is the only one that does, i am assuming its something to do with the .map line any help or point in the right direction would be appreciated.

```
//footer.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Component({
  selector: 'main-footer',
  templateUrl: 'footer.html'
 // styleUrls: ['footer/footer.css']
})
@Injectable()
export class FooterComponent{ 
    constructor (public http: Http) {}
    getJson() {
    this.http.get('app/testjson.json')
    .map(res => res.text())
    .subscribe(
      data => this.showArray(data),
      err => this.handleError(err),
      () => console.log('Random Quote Complete')
    );
    }
    //error handling
    private handleError(error: Response) {
        console.error(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
    }
    //pass the data to console 
    showArray(data){
        console.log(data); 
    }    
}
```

This is where i am not sure how to bind the data

```
// footer.html 
<button (click)="getJson()">Get JSON!</button>
<div *ngFor="let key of data">{{key.league}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the .map line you should get the json, since I presume that your data is in json format.

```
.map(res => res.json())
```

And to show your data, you need to store it first. I would suggest that you create a local variable to save it in and then bind that to the NgFor. For example:

```
let dataToShow = [];

getJson() {
this.http.get('app/testjson.json')
.map(res => res.text())
.subscribe(
  data => this.dataToShow = data,
  err => this.handleError(err),
  () => console.log('Random Quote Complete')
);
}
```

And then you use "dataToShow" in the NgFor instead.

```
<div *ngFor="let key of dataToShow">{{key.league}}</div>
```

Comment: Yea, its just spitting out 100 errors at me when i change it, need to learn how to reduce the debugger to be more targeted, this it might be `Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.`

Comment: What happens when you use "pause on exception" setting? Could give you a clue to where the error is if the stacktrace isn't showing anything useful. If you're using chrome the setting is a little pause sign on the sources tab.